# iOS app crashes when using FirebaseApp.configure()

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to use Firebase cloud messaging in my framework. but where ever I use FirebaseApp.configure in my code, I got crash with nothing but this error message:

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9
```

does anyone have an idea what's going on?

I created project and app in firebase and added GoogleService-Info.plist to my app. and I can receive Push notifications throw APNs. but I just can't register in FCM.

this is the relevant code in AppDelegate.swift:

```
import MyFramework

func application(_ application: UIApplication, willFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    MyFramework.shared.start()

    return true
}
```

and this is code in my framework:

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import FirebaseCore

public class MyFramework: NSObject {
    public static let shared = MyFramework()

    override private init() {}

    public func start() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        let authorizationOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .sound, .badge]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: authorizationOptions, completionHandler: { (granted, error) in
            if let _error = error {
                print(_error.localizedDescription)
            }

            guard granted else {
                return
            }
        })

        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
}
```

Comment: Is ‍`import firebase` added to `MyFramework` or `AppDelegate`?

Comment: edited, see post again

Comment: Is your framework setup correctly?  My guess you're using CocoaPods?

Comment: no, I'm not using cocoa pods, I used dependencies as linked libraries.

Comment: There's really not enough code here to know exactly what the problem is but two things I noticed is you're missing `import Firebase` as well as initializing Firebase should be done in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this sample code in `AppDelegate`, if resolve problem then transfer code to custom class.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    // [START set_messaging_delegate]
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    // [END set_messaging_delegate]

    registerForPushNotifications()

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken as Data
}

func registerForPushNotifications() {

    // iOS 10 support
    if #available(iOS 10, *) {

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){ (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization.

            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
            guard granted else { return }
        }
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings(){ (setttings) in

            switch setttings.soundSetting{
            case .enabled:

                print("enabled sound setting")

            case .disabled:

                print("setting has been disabled")

            case .notSupported:
                print("something vital went wrong here")
            }
        }

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 9 support
    else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 8 support
    else if #available(iOS 8, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
        // iOS 7 support
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications(matching: [.badge, .sound, .alert])
    }
  }
}

// [START ios_10_message_handling]
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    completionHandler()
 }
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]


extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]

    print(dataDict)

    //        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
// [END refresh_token]

// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
// [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

This code work for me correctly. if don't work check other things!

Comment: I know the way to use Firebase Messaging, my problem is dependency management, I'm writing framework, so I can't use FirebaseApp.configre in AppDelegate.